# policy uploading failed.EntitelmentPolicyAdminServiceException wso2

Tags: wso2

I have installed wso2 identity server and logged into wso2 management console. I am trying to import the policies into identity server, but it is showing an error saying that **policy uploading failed. EntitlementPolicyAdminServiceIdentityException**

Can you please tell me how to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share any exceptions printed at server console?

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know the backend error logs that is printed in WSO2 Identity Server console or wso2carbon.log files.  I assume this may be due to that your policy may not be valid according to the schema definition.